# how to create trigger in codeigniter? my code doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

model

```
public function register($table, $data)
{
    return $this->db->insert($table, $data);
}
public function after_register()
        {
            $query = $this->db->query("
                CREATE TRIGGER 'afterinsert_user' AFTER INSERT ON 'user' FOR EACH ROW 
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE user SET id_siswa=NEW.id_user WHERE id_user=NEW.id_user;
                    INSERT INTO siswa VALUES(NEW.id_user,'','','','','','','','');
                END
            ");
            return $query;
        }
```

controller

```
$insert = $this->m_siswa->register("user", $data);    
$trigger = $this->m_siswa->after_register();
```

BUT I GET ERROR

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''afterinsert_user' AFTER INSERT ON 'user' FOR EACH ROW BEGIN ' at line 1

CREATE TRIGGER 'afterinsert_user' AFTER INSERT ON 'user' FOR EACH ROW BEGIN UPDATE user SET id_siswa=NEW.id_user WHERE id_user=NEW.id_user; INSERT INTO siswa VALUES(NEW.id_user,'','','','','','','',''); END

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/meskul/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: You can see the `db` errors with `print_r($this->db->error());`

Comment: why you need to create trigger in codeigniter? cant you just make it directly in your sql?

Comment: remove the quotes from `'afterinsert_user'` and `'user'`